# Is there not one decent email client for Mac?

Tags: mail.app, email, software-recommendation

When I started looking for an alternative to Mail I had no idea it would become a quest. So my criteria have become...

1. One-off purchase (no monthly/annual billing)
2. Pleasant UI
3. Doesn't force me to use an intermediate proxy server
4. Doesn't mine my emails or usage for data
5. Has a solid search
6. Doesn't sporadically lose my recent emails or reset read flags, etc
7. Compatible with Protonmail (should be...just SMTP)
8. I guess should have an iphone version too but I'm willing to be flexible on that
9. Bonus: copy/pastes nicely from places like Notes

Failed contenders:

**Spark:** Free so I presume mines my data. intermediate server? monthly fee above 5GB

**Edison:** Mines you for data

**Newton:** 50/yr and I presume an intermediate server?

**Outlook:** Ugly

**Canary:** Reviewer says it suffers the same issues as Mail and has an equally lousy search

**Airmail:** Is a fairly cheap subscription and one-off for business purchases. People are complaining about the search though

Anyone have an other suggestions? Is there anything genuinely better than Mail? Are my standards too high??

Comment: Funnily enough I've always struggled finding a decent one too... I find myself still stuck with Thunderbird which, although not perfect, just seems like the most reliable. I hated how Outlook would take up half of my hard drive by wanting to sync my entire inbox (with 10 years' worth of email)

Comment: My personal opinion: now when column layout is back Mail is decent enough (at least for me) and should have all requested features ;-). Probably I should consider myself lucky because I can't think what can be "genuinely better".

Comment: "just SMTP" would be one-way communication, send only. Your question doesn't mention what you think is 'wrong' with Mail.

Comment: yeah sorry I meant IMAP/SMTP...  I would think the criteria list implies what I think it wrong with Mail... Well specifically I find the search and the occassional sync issues to be particularly annoying.

Comment: Whats wrong with search? I find it fairly convenient: in Mail ⌥ + ⌘ + F (or invoke Spotlight with ⌘+Space), write something like 'january mails from <name> attachment <type or part of the filename>' and there you are.

Comment: Personally, I think the problem is IMAP… but that's just me. I hate the implementation IMAP has, where deletion on one device is deletion on them all. That's not my idea of safe. I'd investigate whether your current mail provider can use POP & see what it's like if you switch to that. BTW, Points 1,3,4 have nothing to do with any mail app, they're server-side, as is 6 (IMAP issue)

Comment: @AivarPaalberg sometimes it can't find emails with a single word search I'm forced to try to hunt it down by date.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for your thoughts about POP vs IMAP. The points I listed aren't all a direct criticism of Mail, more of Mail alternatives most of which impose server-side middleman services on you.

Comment: A mail app is a mail app - they're pretty simple things, haven't changed much in the 30 years I've been using them. Any "middleman" aspect is that of the ISP/mail provider, not the app.

Comment: Yup, it is problematic:  Mail missing emails from 4th March which i realise after 20 min of searching for a phrase I know should exist. Then I look on the webmail for my provider and they are indeed there.  Shouldn't these things be in sync?

Comment: @HariHonor Yes but I would bet on your mail provider having the issue not Mail

Comment: Lol @Tetsujin my answer is the exact opposite of your comment here. Not attacking you directly, but I see things differently. If all you need from email is what existed 30 years ago, let’s all use `elm`

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily suggest that losing emails is the fault of the client. In my epxerience, Apple Mail meets all your criteria, with the possible exception of Protonmail, because I don't know, and Pleasant UI, because that's subjective.

Comment: @bmike - tbh, it **is** all I need from email. I send some, I receive some. I file it all locally to a myriad relevant folders on one master repository Mac [backed up to the hilt, of course] & throw away what I don't need. I don't require or indeed ever want sync to my phone - in fact I always immediately delete all mail from my phone… because it's on the Mac. I have mail back to 2001, when I first moved from an office to a home environment & bought my own domain.

Comment: My only real issue with it is my provider are now subservient to Outlook which causes me admin issues [not email issues] as I used to be able to admin all users on my domain but MS365/Outlook won't let me. I consider that a major fail. Additionally, though I use POP acess the underlying method is IMAP, which means Outlook have legible versions of all my mail on their servers. I consider this a breach of my privacy as I owe nothing to Microsoft & wouldn't touch them with a barge-pole were it not for this structure I've been forced into.

Comment: Agreed @Tetsujin I published my thoughts on outlook. Microsoft apps are light years better than they were a decade ago - native Apple features and very responsive developers + cycles. Despite all that positive momentum,  my paycheck is why I use them, not by preference. I feel this question is +1 I may disagree with the criteria, but OP went out on a limb and expressed their needs - how is that not useful for an objective and healthy subjective question here? I hope people vote on the quality of the discussion and not that they have the exact same needs as Hari here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer: [Postbox](https://www.postbox-inc.com/)

It misses #8 (no mobile version) and #9 is so-so (loses some formatting but I'm thinking it's Notes that's the problem)...but it is very stylish, snappy, and seems to have a lot of nice UX innovations (e.g. quick replies below every email, sort emails into folders with pre-defined keystrokes, themes...)

Answer (score 1):

No, email is a remnant of a more civilized time when text was text and email didn’t have to include such things as a JavaScript engine and image rendering and a security apparatus.

- elm / pine / lynx used to be enough for email and web browsing but now you’ve got requirements that are at odds with plain text display. (And we’re all in the same boat as you - your ask is reasonable on the surface but unlikely to be met in a substantial way.)

On a practical level, I have had better success with choosing a mail client to match the mail provider and choosing a mail provider that makes Apple’s first party client work better by better managing the content that gets to my device in the first place.

- Work is Microsoft, so outlook it is. (warts and opinions on beauty are assuaged by a paycheck.)
- [Fastmail](https://www.fastmail.com/) has provided sanity to me for mail I manage. It works well
  with the native client and it’s own app / web app are well designed
  to my eye. I can afford it, and their business model adds value to me. Not everyone wants to fund a service that makes their mail work with native clients, though.
- [Hey + Basecamp](https://basecamp.com/about/software) seemed promising but I can’t seem to navigate the pain that burning bridges to the past would entail to make a run at using [Hey for my email](https://hey.com/).

Just like security software, email changes constantly and how you fund the salaries of people skilled enough to care about optimizing your time with decent software may be at odds with paying them once for software you expect to work in a month or need support in 6 months.

Just like dozens of companies before it, I wish Postbox (and all newcomers to the space) well, but lifetime support on a fixed price purchase is hard to see as anything but a Ponzi scheme. Whether a company is VC funded or bootstrapping it, developing a popular mail client that do a better job than Apple’ first party client is a money-losing operation for the foreseeable future. Until enough people want to pay substantial money regularly, I don’t see a business model for the innovation you seek in this space.

As a postscript, if you don’t buy into mail and standards as the cause of this mess - have a read on how we can’t even agree what a valid email address might be. With that one header field still up in the air for implementation in a standard manner, a proper email client surely can’t be made today to a common standard of use.

- https://www.netmeister.org/blog/email.html

I look forward to other people’s solutions to a gnarly problem and some requirements I can’t see being met in the next 4 years or so in a manner that was possible in past decades.

Comment: Thanks bmike. I appreciate the detailed reply and the heads up about "Hey". I hear you too about funding the devs to keep up with the tech... I guess that's why most are offering subscription models.  Same with music players actually.